# Spring Data UPDATE query having existing values

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

Wish to know how to write the following MySQL query either in Spring Data / Query DSL

`update PLAN set PLAN.sell_price = PLAN.cost_price * 1.5 where PLAN.type = 'SAL'`

Answer (score 1):

i think the only way to achieve this is to use `native` in your JpaRepository

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "update PLAN set PLAN.sell_price = PLAN.cost_price * ?1 where PLAN.type = ?2")
void updatePlans(Double multiplier, String planTuype);
```